# Diameter of inscribed circle

Tags: circles

[image: incribed circle]

How can i express diameter of inscribed circle in terms of radius of three circles.

Comment: [Descrates' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem)

Comment: @achillehui: Very interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a=\frac{1}{R_1},\, b=\frac{1}{R_2},\, c=\frac{1}{R_3},\, x=\frac{1}{R},\, $ then

$x = a+b+c+2\sqrt{ab+bc+ac}$

I don't know derivation of this relationship. Discovered him famous British chemist F. Soddy.

This relationship is known from Czech books on recreational mathematics from 1967.